# How do i get a TDataset to store empty string instead of null?

Tags: delphi, tdataset

I have a required field in my database (NOT NULL), but empty strings are allowed.

How do I get a delphi TDataset to work with this? With the required property of the field object set to either true or false it still seems to be trying to store null instead of an empty string.

For info im using a TIBDataset and a TIBStringField.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you can set the value in the `OnBeforePost` like this:

```
if IBDataSet1.FieldByName('OPTION_TEXT').IsNull then
begin
  IBDataset1.FieldByName('OPTION_TEXT').Value = '';
end;
```

However, TIBStringField has an unpublished property `EmptyAsNull` which you must set to `False`. The default value is `True`. When this feature is enabled, the dataset does you a favor and converts empty strings to `NULL`:

You can turn it off like this:

```
if IBDataSet1.FieldByName('OPTION_TEXT').IsNull then
begin
  TIBStringField(IBDataset1.FieldByName('OPTION_TEXT')).EmptyAsNull := False;
  IBDataset1.FieldByName('OPTION_TEXT').Value = '';
end;
```

Alternatively, you could set the `EmptyAsNull` property on the string fields in your form's `OnCreate` if you are using static (design time) fields, or wherever your create your fields.

Answer (score 3):

TField has property for default value, but it is string and unfortunately empty string means that there is no default value, so it doesn't help in your case.
But you can catch OnBeforePost event from dataset and check, if field is NULL then set it up with empty string.

Comment: How would I do this? In the OnBeforePost routine I've added this;  if IBDataset1.FieldByName('OPTION_TEXT').IsNull then
    IBDataset1.FieldByName('OPTION_TEXT').Value := '';

Comment: @srayner Yes, it should be enough.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add that this doesn't work because is gives 'validation error for column OPTION_TEXT, value ''*** null ***''

Comment: @srayner Probably you changed property Required of TField to True. Change it back to default value (False).

Comment: No it's set to false. If you make it true, then it states OPTION_TEXT must have a value.

Comment: @srayner I neverr used TIBStringField, but if there is property EmptyAsNull (as Marcus mentioned), try to set it False from the code (at OnCreate section for example).